# Kotlin sorting nulls last

Tags: sorting, kotlin

What would be a Kotlin way of sorting list of objects by nullable field with nulls last?

Kotlin object to sort:

```
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
data class SomeObject(
    val nullableField: String?
)
```

Analogue to below Java code:

```java
@Test
public void name() {
    List<SomeObject> sorted = Stream.of(new SomeObject("bbb"), new SomeObject(null), new SomeObject("aaa"))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SomeObject::getNullableField, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
            .collect(toList());

    assertEquals("aaa", sorted.get(0).getNullableField());
    assertNull(sorted.get(2).getNullableField());
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
private static class SomeObject {
    private String nullableField;
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use these functions from the [`kotlin.comparisons`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/index.html) package:

- [`fun <T: Comparable<T>> nullsLast(): Comparator<T?>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/nulls-last.html), which constructs a comparator of something comparable that just puts `null`s after all not-null values;
- [`fun <T, K> compareBy(comparator: Comparator<in K>, selector: (T) -> K): Comparator<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html), which accepts a comparator and a function that provides values for the comparator, combining them into a new comparator;

This will let you make a comparator that compares `SomeObject` by `nullableField` putting `null`s last. Then you can simply pass the comparator to 
[`fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortedWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): List<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html), which sorts an iterable into a list using a comparator:

```
val l = listOf(SomeObject(null), SomeObject("a"))

l.sortedWith(compareBy(nullsLast<String>()) { it.nullableField }))
// [SomeObject(nullableField=a), SomeObject(nullableField=null)]
```

Comment: A small addition here, when comparing descending: 
`compareByDescending(nullsLast<String>(), { it.nullableField })` would actually sort the null values on first positions, so maybe it would make more sense, and be clearer to write the code like so:  `sortedWith(nullsLast(compareBy { it.nullableField }))` or its complementary: `sortedWith(nullsLast(compareByDescending { it.nullableField }))`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html#compareby) and pass [`nullsLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/nulls-last.html#nullslast) as comparator like so:

```
val elements = listOf(SomeObject("bbb"), SomeObject(null), SomeObject("aaa"))

val sorted = elements.sortedWith(compareBy<SomeObject,String?>(nullsLast(), { it.name }))

println(sorted) //-> [SomeObject(name=aaa), SomeObject(name=bbb), SomeObject(name=null)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nullsLast](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/nulls-last.html#nullslast) and pass  [compareBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html#compareby) as comparator like so:

```
val sortedValues = mutableListOf(1 to "a", 2 to null, 7 to "c", 6 to "d", 5 to "c", 6 to "e")

sortedValues.sortWith(nullsLast(compareBy { it.second }))

println(sortedValues)
```

Comment: This does not do anything more than if the `nullsLast()` function was not in the code.

Comment: Initially, I also tried this approach and struggled why it doesn't work.
It doesn't work because `nullsLast()` here is applied to the object (instances of `Pair` in your example) but it should be applied to the property the selector picks (`it.second` in your example).