# Kotlin sort array of objects by null values first, then descending

Tags: arrays, sorting, kotlin

I'd like to sort a Kotlin array of objects, with nulls first and then sort values descending.
This is similar to [Kotlin sorting nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802047/kotlin-sorting-nulls-last) but with a bit different sorting.

```
data class stuff(
    var value: String? = null, // null possible here
    var value2: String = "" 
) {
    fun debug(): String { return "\n $value: $value2" }
}

fun main() {
    val someArray = arrayOf(
        stuff(value="1", value2="1st non null"),
        stuff(value=null, value2="a null key"),
        stuff(value="3", value2="3rd non null"),
        stuff(value=null, value2="another null"),
        stuff(value="2", value2="2nd non null"),
    )
    println("unsorted array: ${someArray.map{ it.debug() }}")

    someArray.sortByDescending{it.value}
    println("\nsorted array: ${someArray.map{ it.debug() }}")

    someArray.sortWith(nullsLast(compareBy { it.value }))
    println("\nsorted array another way: ${someArray.map{ it.debug() }}")
}
```

This currently outputs:

```
unsorted array: [
 1: 1st non null, 
 null: a null key, 
 3: 3rd non null, 
 null: another null, 
 2: 2nd non null]

sorted array: [
 3: 3rd non null, 
 2: 2nd non null, 
 1: 1st non null, 
 null: a null key, 
 null: another null]

sorted array another way: [
 null: a null key, 
 null: another null, 
 1: 1st non null, 
 2: 2nd non null, 
 3: 3rd non null]
```

I'd like it to sort like this (with the null order not mattering, but descending the rest):

```
[
 null: a null key, 
 null: another null, 
 3: 3rd non null,
 2: 2nd non null,
 1: 1st non null]
```

How could I do this efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: There's also a `nullsFirst()` function and `compareByDescending()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I figured one way out. It seems like there should be a more convenient and efficient way though.

```
someArray.sortWith(compareByDescending<stuff,String?>(nullsLast(), { it.value }))
```

Comment: it can be a little more simple `someArray.sortWith(compareByDescending(nullsLast()) { it.value })`